# MQRFH2.usr coming in the main message body

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-6.1

Using WMQ7.0 with WMB 6.1

I have one flow where I am transforming a message and using **MQRFH2.usr** for holding some data.

But, I am facing the issue where the **MQRFH2.usr** is coming in the main message body.

I have deployed the same code in different environments, but I am getting this issue only in one environment.

So, it **doesn't seems to be a code issue**. It has something to do with **configurations.**

Kindly, suggest what could be the possible cause.

Comment: I guess this is one more tumbleweed batch for me... :D

Comment: What version of WMQ QMgrs are in use?

Comment: @T.Rob All queuemanagers are on WMQ 7.0

Answer (score 1):

Check the queue's [`PROPCTL`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzao.doc/mi203606.htm) setting.  If this is set to `NONE` then the behavior is as follows:

> If the application does not create a message handle, all the message
>   properties are removed from the MQRFH2. Name/value pairs in the MQRFH2
>   headers are left in the message.

Be sure to read the [doc page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzao.doc/mi203606.htm) through a couple of times and maybe test with different settings to understand fully how `PROPCTL` modifies the message content your app receives.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Actually in my case issue was with the MQMD.FORMAT which should have been 'MQRFH2', but it was 'MQSTR' instead. But, still don't know how it is working fine with WMB 8 and WMQ 7.0 combination.It only failed with WMB6.1 and WMQ 7.0 combination.

Comment: Run a trace.  I expect you'll find that WMB 6 doesn't set `MQGMO_PROPERTIES` but that WMB 8 sets it to one of the values described [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_properties_gmo.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The MQRFH2 headers, if present, always come in the payload part of the message (that's the way webpshere organizes it). You can receive one or more MQRFH2 headers (structures).

Perhaps you are expecting only one and are receiving two? This would explain your message data being left with gibberish.

I use the following code to handler these heards upon receiving a message

```
MQRFH2 header = null;

// Find and store message length
int msglen = replyMessage.getMessageLength();

MQHeaderList list = new MQHeaderList(replyMessage);
int indexOf = list.indexOf("MQRFH2");
if (indexOf >= 0) {
    header = (MQRFH2) list.get(indexOf);
    msglen = msglen - header.size();
}

String msgText = replyMessage.readStringOfCharLength(msglen);
```

Hope it helps.

Martins